# pg_upgrade doesn't find config file

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to upgrade PostgreSQL on Ubuntu Server from 9.6 to 10. This is the first time I'm doing this. The server doesn't contain any useful data yet but I want to make sure I can do this properly next time.

I followed the instructions in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html). Here's what I did:

- Installed the new packages for version 10
- Stopped both versions on the server
- Ran the pg_upgrade script:

  sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_upgrade -b /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin -B /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin -d /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/ -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/

This is the console output:

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

*failure*
Consult the last few lines of "pg_upgrade_server.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.

connection to database failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/lib/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.50432"?

could not connect to source postmaster started with the command:
"/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/" -o "-p 50432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directories='/var/lib/postgresql'" start
Failure, exiting
```

This is the contents of pg_upgrade_server.log:

```
command: "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/" -o "-p 50432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directories='/var/lib/postgresql'" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1
waiting for server to start....postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

I'm totally confused now. What should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You know what they say about the word *assume*

### I assumed the config dir and data dir was the same.
Answer 1:

Change your command to this and it will work.

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_upgrade \
-b /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin -B /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin \
-d /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/ -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/
-o '-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf' \
-O '-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf'
```

we can provide the special config file location as an option

<s>Also, I believe you have identified a default install issue or the documentation needs to be updated</s>

The default install should create the config files in the datadir

### Answer 2:

Since this is play, try this too:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dropcluster 10 main
sudo -u postgres pg_upgradecluster 9.6 main
```

### Keeping this, since it might help someone else.

The empty databases seem to have not been created yet. Or are in a different directory. That's why postgresql.conf is not found in the error message.

`ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`

should show two files.

The equivalent initdb command for both versions should be run

```
pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main initdb

pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main initdb
```

Comment: The `ls` command shows no files. But both databases already exist. They were created by the package installer and I've already played a bit with the old (9.6) version. Both server instances were already running. Not sure what all the paths are about. The pg_upgrade documentation isn't very helpful with that. No examples.

Comment: So the paths in the pg_upgrade command (-d -D) are the locations of where the data (and config files) are stored by postgres.
Use the `ps` or `find` command to locate both config files and use those directories in the pg_upgrade command

Comment: They're in different directories: /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf for the config and /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/ for the data. That's how Postgres' original package for Ubuntu/Debian does it. Is that packaging incompatible with Postgres' own tools?

Comment: So I was wrong to say that -d & -D are location of where the data and config files are. It's actually the *config directory*. Thanks - I learnt something today and the documentation needs to be updated too

Comment: Thanks, it worked with the config directory. The documentation seems wrong here.

Comment: Thanks, I made some progress following this answer. However both the old and new options parameters should have `-c` before the `config_file` so `-o '-c config_file=/path/to/postgresql.conf'`. Also, I think the 3rd line in your Answer 1 is missing a backslash.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, doing an upgrade from postgres 9.5 to 12, the comment by @hsebastian about adding `-c` was crucial.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently did DB upgrade from `8.4` to `11`, on same machine, using `pg_upgrade`.

Issue was that in `8.4` instance, configuration file - `postgresql.conf`, **`unix_socket_directory`** parameter **was empty**.

Changes as below, in `8.4` `postgresql.conf`:

```js
unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

solved the issue.