# Upgrading postgres to 10 from 9.5 using pg_upgradecluster

Tags: postgresql

I am testing the process of upgrading postgres to 10 from 9.5

I am following the steps as mentioned in this [link](https://gist.github.com/dmitrykustov/27c673ec4f7abd716912e4c830910019) -

```
dmanna@ubuntu:~$ pg_lsclusters 
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
10  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log

sudo pg_dropcluster 10 main --stop
sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main -m upgrade
sudo pg_dropcluster 9.5 main
```

Can someonet let me know the following

1. If there is a way I can check if the upgrade will be successful
   before going for the actual upgrade?
2. If I am using the link option
   in the upgrade can I still use the `sudo pg_dropcluster 9.5 main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To check for compatibility, etc use the native upgrade command with check option.

`pg_upgrade —check`
Refer to the the [pg_upgrade doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) for details. <s>And remember ([just found out for Ubuntu today](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/190469/32562)), datadir is actually the location of the dir which has the config files (hba, ident, pg.conf).</s>

2. If the —link option is used

   sudo pg_dropcluster 9.5 main

should be run. IIRC pg_upgradecluster starts the db cluster automatically.

If you follow pg_upgrade route, there is defined point where the old cluster can still be used/ rolled back to.